# Tracking orders which placed using a specific button

Tags: magento, google-analytics, tracking, pageviews

I am trying to track the orders in Google analytics which placed after cliking on a specific button.

To be more specific there is a '**Upgrade**' button for each of the product on listing page.
Requirement is, we need to track only those orders which placed as a result of clicking this upgrade button.

Any suggestion how can I track these type of orders?

Answer (score 0):

Look into Google Analytics "Event Tracking" to see if it is applicable.

The following code snippet enables tracking add-to-cart events.

```
<button type="button" id="gat-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(); submitGaTrack(); return false;"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>

<?php $gatSku = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9-\s]+/", "", $_product->getSku()); $gatName = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9-\/\s]+/", "", $_product->getName()); $gatPrice = intval($_product->getPrice()); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitGaTrack() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'addtocart', '<?php echo $gatSku; ?>', '<?php echo $gatName; ?>', <?php echo $gatPrice; ?>, true]);
    }
</script>
```